# Using Tee Chart in javascript

Tags: javascript, teechart

How to create Tee chart in MVC4 using JavaScript/ Ajax?

Can we create multiple axes in Tee chart through java script?

Chart: Four Line and one Bar type with multiple axes.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the examples in the online TeeChart for JavaScript/HTML5 demo?
http://www.steema.com/files/public/teechart/html5/v2012.12.14.1.4/demos/

Take a look at the "Axes\Multiple Axes" demo.

```
  Chart1=new Tee.Chart("canvas1");

  // Add four line series, with 200 random points each:

  Chart1.addSeries(new Tee.Line()).addRandom(200);
  Chart1.addSeries(new Tee.Candle()).addRandom(200);
  Chart1.addSeries(new Tee.Area()).addRandom(200);
  Chart1.addSeries(new Tee.Area()).addRandom(200);
  Chart1.addSeries(new Tee.Line()).addRandom(200);

  // Create additional axes:

  var axis1=Chart1.axes.left;
  var axis2=Chart1.axes.add(false,false);
  var axis3=Chart1.axes.add(false,false);
  var axis4=Chart1.axes.add(false,false);

  // Setup axis positions as % percent:

  axis1.start= 0; axis1.end=25;
  axis2.start=25; axis2.end=40;
  axis3.start=40; axis3.end=75;
  axis4.start=75; axis4.end=100;

  Chart1.axes.bottom.setMinMax(0,DISPLAY_RANGE);

  // Set series with axes:

  Chart1.series.items[1].vertAxis=axis2;
  Chart1.series.items[2].vertAxis=axis3;
  Chart1.series.items[3].vertAxis=axis4;
  Chart1.series.items[4].vertAxis=axis3;
```